# How to make postback button click event from running twice to once into asp .net?

Tags: asp.net

trigger twice result in inserting double records in database.

How to make insert once

Comment: Post the code from the event.

Comment: I posted, sorry for late reply, today i have many meeting

Answer (score 1):

You can add javascript to disable the button when the click event is fired.

```
MyButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;" + Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(MyButton, "").ToString());
```

Code from: http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/10/06/how-to-disable-an-asp-net-button-when-clicked.aspx

Comment: it do not run click event, Save_Button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;" + Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this.Save_Button, "").ToString());

Comment: Could you post what you see for the button in the page source?  The key is that the first "click" should disable the button using javascript.  Is that happening?  Is there a chance the page is refreshing before you click the second time?

Comment: I discover the query = query + something run twice